# What does resource $title do and how to use it?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

```
class OpsServer extends Resource
{


    /**
     * The model the resource corresponds to.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $model = \App\OpsServer::class;


    /**
     * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $title = 'name';
```

What does resource $title do and how to use it?

I think it can not do anything

Comment: OpsServer object then simply object->title?

Answer (score 2):

When a resource is shown within the search results, the results will display the "title" of the resource. For example, a `Role` resource may use the `name` attribute as its title, or `Post` resource may use the `title` attribute. Then, when the resource is shown within the global search results, that attribute will be displayed.

[image]

To customize the "title" attribute of a resource, you may define a `title` property on the resource class:

```php
/**
 * The single value that should be used to represent the resource when being displayed.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public static $title = 'name';
```

Alternatively, you may override the resource's `title` method:

```php
/**
 * Get the value that should be displayed to represent the resource.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function title()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```